# Writing Bitmap to OpenXML ImagePart via MemoryStream

Tags: openxml

I have an image stored in a Bitmap object that I'd like to stick into an OpenXML document.  I've tried using a MemoryStream as an intermediate step as follows:

```
ImagePart part = container.AddNewPart<ImagePart>("image/jpeg", imageId);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    part.FeedData(ms);
}
```

but that always results in empty files in the media folder and PowerPoint displaying an error instead of the images.  I know that the MemoryStream has the image data correctly as I've written it out to a file without issue.  When I try to load an image from a FileStream it works just fine.

How can I get this Bitmap into an OpenXML document?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was almost there, I just needed to reset the MemoryStream's position to the beginning after saving the Bitmap to it.

```
ms.Position = 0;
```

That line should be added between the `Save` and `FeedData` calls.

Comment: a very important tip in my opinion